# Error during Hyperledger Composer network install: npm ERR! command failed with node-gyp rebuild

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to install a network on Hyperledger Composer using the following command:

`composer network install -c PeerAdmin@HealthData-network -a healthdata-network@0.0.1.bna`

However, I'm encountering an error related to npm and node-gyp rebuild. Here's the error log:

`2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! code 1  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! path /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! command failed  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/chaincode/output/node_modules/x509/build'  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! CXX(target) Release/obj.target/x509/src/addon.o  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/chaincode/output/node_modules/x509/build'  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok  2024-03-26 12:04:35 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1`

dockker-compose.yml
`
version: "2"

services:
elasticsearch:
image: webhippie/elasticsearch:6.8
environment:
- ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
ca.org1.example.com:
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
platform: linux/amd64
environment:
- FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
ports:
- "7054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/19ab65abbb04807dad12e4c0a9aaa6649e70868e3abd0217a322d89e47e1a6ae_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
- ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca.org1.example.com

orderer.example.com:
container_name: orderer.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
platform: linux/amd64
environment:
- ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
- ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
- ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
- ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-genesis.block
- ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
- ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: orderer
ports:
- 7050:7050
volumes:
- ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
- ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp

peer0.org1.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
environment:
- CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER=custom-ccenv:latest
- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
- CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
- CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
- CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
- CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
- CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
- CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
- CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=adekunle
- CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=mypassword
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
ports:
- 7051:7051
- 7053:7053
volumes:
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
- ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
- ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
- ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
depends_on:
- orderer.example.com
- couchdb

couchdb:
container_name: couchdb
image: couchdb:3.3.3
ports:
- 5984:5984
environment:
COUCHDB_USER: adekunle
COUCHDB_PASSWORD: mypassword
DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
`

I've also attached my Docker Compose file for reference. Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

`composer network install -c PeerAdmin@HealthData-network -a healthdata-network@0.0.1.bna`

Expecting success responnse

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).